# What is the difference between Charge transfer and Electron transfer?

Tags: organometallic-compounds

This problem was given to me yesterday that What is the difference between Charge transfer and Electron transfer? I was taking it thesame though the professor have given me some hint that charge transfer is of two types which are Metal to ligand charge transfer (MLCT) and Ligand to Metal Charge transfer (LMCT) and he defined electron transfer as the movement of electrons from one molecular species (donor) to another molecular species (acceptor),I need the actual  difference between the two. please help I have exam tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

In a polar molecule of hydrogen chloride, there is a charge transfer from hydrogen to chlorine atom, but not an electron transfer. There is an electron transfer between them during hydration and dissociation.

The charge transfer is a fractional transfer of a charge, based on the shift of the electron density, caused by electronegativity difference or by orbital configuration rearrangement.

The electron transfer is a transfer of an electron as a charged particle, making the left molecular entity more positive and making the entity the electron lands on more negative.